# $\frac{\partial f (x_0)}{\partial x_j}$ exists if and only if directional derivative of $f(x)$ at $x_0$ in the direction of $e_j$ and $-e_j$ exist

Tags: real-analysis

Let E be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $f:E\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a function, let
$x_0$ be an interior point of E, and let 1 ≤ j ≤ n. Now we have to Show that $\frac{\partial f (x_0)}{\partial x_j}$ exists
if and only if $D_{e_j}f(x_0)$ and $D_{−e_j}f(x_0)$ exist, where $D_{e_j}f(x_0)$ is directional derivative of $f(x)$ at $x_0$ in the direction $e_j$ where $e_j$ is unit vector.

Now in my book from definition  of directional derivative,partial derivative, I have
$$D_{e_j}f(x_0)=\lim{t\to 0;t \gt 0}{\frac{f(x_0+te_j)-f(x_0)}{t}}$$
And
$$D_{-e_j}f(x_0)=\lim{t\to 0;t \gt 0}{\frac{f(x_0+t(-e_j))-f(x_0)}{t}}$$
And
$$\frac{\partial f (x_0)}{\partial x_j}=\lim{t\to 0}{\frac{f(x_0+te_j)-f(x_0)}{t}}$$

$\Rightarrow$
If $\frac{\partial f (x_0)}{\partial x_j}$ exists then looking at the limit can we say that $D_{e_j}f(x_0)$ And $D_{−ej}f(x_0)$ exist?

$\Leftarrow$
I have know idea how to prove this side, please help.

Comment: if and only if what?

Comment: If and only if Directional derivative of f(x) at  $x_0$ in the directiom of $e_j$ and $-e_j$ exist

Comment: It would be good to say so in the title and the question itself.